# With areas, can I break my application out into different modules easily?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Say I am making an application that I want to break out functionality such that I can turn features on/off.

I was thinking of doing this:

```
1. breaking major functionality out using areas
2. all business logic (other than controller logic) but in a seperate assembly
3. have a 'base' assembly that is shared with all other assemblies
```

So say I have a CMS module, a ecommerce module, etc.  I would have those in their own area, and then have a seperate CMS assembly and ecommerce assembly.  Each assembly would have module and db access code, and business logic etc.

Is this a good idea?  Is there a better way?  Will this work?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's generally a good idea to separate the functional areas of an application like that. Isolation helps with testing and with maintainability. It's also important to look for commonalities and to see how it all comes together. Take a look at the [SOLID principles](http://butunclebob.com/ArticleS.UncleBob.PrinciplesOfOod), they'll guide your designs. There're also a set of package design principles in that link that can help with allocation of functionality to assemblies.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but the areas alone are only half of the solution IMHO.

For better modularization, it is advisable to use self-contained assemblies for the "pluggable" web parts as well, which can easily be achieved with the [MvcContrib](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/) [Portable Areas](http://lostechies.com/erichexter/2009/11/01/asp-net-mvc-portable-areas-via-mvccontrib/) (which extend on the areas and provide the files from via a virtual path provider out of embedded assembly resources).